# how to run watch script in pnpm workspace

Tags: node.js, typescript, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

If I have structure like this

```
packages
  - alice
  - bar
  - foo
package.json
```

alice, bar, foo are three sub packages. bar is the dependency of alice.
Every sub package has its own watch script defined in package.json. Now, I add a script like`pnpm -r run watch`, it will get stuck, because watch script won't finished and pnpm awaits each command to finish before running the next. So we can add `parallel` to run them in parallel, like `pnpm -r --parallel run watch`, but it still get error in the first run, because bar isn't finished, alice can't resolve bar correctly. see [github](https://github.com/colgin/pnpm-monorepo-demo/tree/feat/parallel_dev)

So is there any workarounds to make this work.

I find [Manage Monorepo with pnpm](https://egoist.dev/pnpm-monorepo), he got the same issue, and I think he didn't find a elegant way to solve this.

And I find the [vitest](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/blob/main/package.json#L11) use `pnpm -r --parallel --filter=./packages/** run dev`, and it works, I have no idea why vitest just works